# Get VID PID from Device ID in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to PowerShell and I want for a USB key plugged, to retrieve some info. Right now my script is:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_diskdrive | 
    ForEach-Object{ 
        $disk = $_
        $_.GetRelated('Win32_PnPEntity')|
        ForEach-Object{ 
            $pnp = $_
            $_.GetRelated('Win32_USBController') |
            ForEach-Object{
                $usb = $_
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    SerialNumber = $disk.SerialNumber
                    Model = $disk.Model
                    Size = $disk.Size
                    if ($usb.DeviceID -match '.*VID_(?<vid>[0-9A-F]{4})&PID_(?<pid>[0-9A-F]{4}).*') {VID=$matches['vid']; PID=$matches['pid']}

                    
                }   
            }
       }
}
```

The line beginning with

```
if ($usb.DeviceID -match '.*VID_(?<vid>[0-9A-F]{4})&PID_(?<pid>[0-9A-F]{4}).*') {VID=$matches['vid']; PID=$matches['pid']}
```

does not work. I want to translate deviceid (which I can get by doing `USBDeviceID = $usb.DeviceID`) ID in PID UID directly.

It throws the following error

> Error with code “Missing = operator after key in hash literal" for the statement "if ($usb.DeviceID -match '.* ...

What am I missing ? many thanks for helping me .

Gerald

Comment: Hey Theo thanks for reply and I will test this solution this weekend. Had a hard time with my machine those last days (HDD crash), that's why I didn't reply earlier. Thanks for sharing your knowledge. Gerald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the way you intend to add properties to the PsCustomObject is wrong.

Either do this:

```
$result = [PsCustomObject]@{
    SerialNumber = $disk.SerialNumber
    Model        = $disk.Model
    Size         = $disk.Size
}
# add items to the object if the condition is true
if ($usb.DeviceID -match '.*VID_(?<vid>[0-9A-F]{4})&PID_(?<pid>[0-9A-F]{4}).*') {
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'VID' -Value $matches['vid']
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'PID' -Value $matches['pid']
}
# output the PsCustomObject
$result
```

or use a Hashtable as temporary storage:

```
# create a Hastable to temporarily store results in
$hash = [ordered]@{
    SerialNumber = $disk.SerialNumber
    Model        = $disk.Model
    Size         = $disk.Size
}
# add items to the hash if the condition is true
if ($usb.DeviceID -match '.*VID_(?<vid>[0-9A-F]{4})&PID_(?<pid>[0-9A-F]{4}).*') {
    $hash['VID']=$matches['vid']
    $hash['PID']=$matches['pid']
}
# next cast to PsCustomObject and output
[PsCustomObject]$hash
```